# Android make .Gif out of Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, save, export, gif

I have an app where the user saves a bunch of bitmaps in a folder on the SD card. I would like to add a feature where the user can export said bitmaps as a .gif file that is viewable say, in a text message. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a native library that does exactly this.
http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/android/index.html#gifflen

Comment: if you seek for a java lib, this lib can be found here: http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/12/04/j2me-animated-gif-encoder/